# List the department names of all the employees working on a project

Tags: mysql, select

I am working with a mysql DB called company with Tables:

```
Employee-> |id_emp|fName|lName|id_Dept|

Department-> |id_Dept|dName|

Project-> |id_Proj|pName|id_Dept|status|budget|actBudget|

Emp_Proj-> |id_Emp|id_Proj|
```

I am still having a problem with how to run queries that work with the emp_proj join table.

The question is "List the dept names of all the employees working on a project.

```sql
SELECT d.dName
FROM department d
JOIN ?????
WHERE id_Emp = id_Proj ???
```

I'm not sure what to join b/c each employee has an id_Dept, and each employee working (or not working) on a project is shown in table emp_proj, so i'm not sure how to SELECT id_Emp working on a project and then compare that with the employee table to reference their id_Dept, and then output those dNames (dept names).

Can anyone help with this type of Query syntax?  Tnx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT dName FROM Department 
INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.id_Dept = Department.id_Dept 
INNER JOIN Emp_Proj ON Employee.id_emp = Emp_Proj.id_Emp 
INNER JOIN Project ON Project.id_Proj = Emp_Proj.id_Proj 
WHERE Project.pName = 'Whotever'
```

This smells like a school project. If so please make sure you understand what this query means and why it works

Comment: It is indeed and thanks for the response.  I am new to INNER JOINs and mysql...i did not realize that your can use multiple INNER JOINs in one query.  I am mulling over it's meaning b/c i have to apply it to similar instances....tnx!